# Can't get ngAnimate to work in new angular-seed project

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, angular-seed

Problem: Animation is not working in angular-seed project.
What I did:

1. I fetched angular-seed from github.
2. In the seed-project there are two views, view1.html and view2.html connected nicely though route with their corresponding controllers.
3. I replace view1 with my simpliest CSS-transission, animation. (which works fine in another project)
4. In View1's script i inject 'ngAnimate' to the module like so:
    var animation3App = angular.module('animation3', ['ngAnimate']);
5. I add  "angular-animate": "1.2.x", to bower.json and run bower install. I verify that angular-animate got added/installed to the bower_components directory.
6. To index.html I add this line just between angular-route and app.js like this: 
   ...src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"...

The animation:
Two  on top of each other, clicking on one should put its opacity to 0, the others (that is underneath to 1) thus changing the image from one to the other, taking its time, 1 second, to change the opacity giving a "merge" effect.

When navigating to index.html routing gives me view1.html, that's how the angular-seed is routed, I didn't touch that. The animation that works perfectly well if not in a angular-seed project doesn't work. The images get swapped but without the animation effect.

I don't get any warnings or errors in browser's F12 tool. 
Is there some way to debug this with batarang?

The whole view1.html with the script inside of it for simplicity:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="animation3">
<head lang="en">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body ng-controller="animation3Ctrl">

<style>
    #image-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .image-back{
        position: absolute;
        top: 25px;
        left: 25px;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 1px lightcoral solid;
    }
    .image-front{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto; /*height: 200px;*/
        border: 1px lightcoral solid;
    }

    .animate-show {
        opacity:1;
    }
    .animate-show.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
    .animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
        -webkit-transition:all 1.7s;
        transition:all 1.7s;
    }
    .animate-show.ng-hide {
        opacity:0;
    }
</style>

<pre>
    This is view1.
    Click on Image to see animation.
    This HTML works perfectly well on it's own, but NOT inside this angular-seed project.
</pre>

<div id="image-container">
    <img class="image-front animate-show"
         ng-src="./img/{{photo.imgFront}}"
         ng-click="flipPhoto()"
         ng-show="frontShown">
    <img class="image-back animate-show"
         ng-src="./img/{{photo.imgBack}}"
         ng-click="flipPhoto()"
         ng-hide="frontShown">
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script>
    var animation3App = angular.module('animation3', ['ngAnimate']);

    animation3App.controller('animation3Ctrl', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {
            $scope.photo = {
                imgBack: 'proXoftLogo.png',
                imgFront: 'donaldBlack.jpg'
            }

            $scope.flipPhoto = function flipPhoto(){
                $scope.frontShown = !$scope.frontShown;
            }
        }]);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!
There was an error in the CSS for the animation.
The 6 steps I describe in my question were all correct.
My problem had nothing to do with angular-seed.

Solution:
I changed the CSS has to this:
(exactly which part is the critical one I don't know yet since I'm learning animations in angular)

```
.animate-show.ng-hide-add,
.animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
    -webkit-transition:all 1.7s;
    transition:all 1.7s;
}
.animate-show.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.animate-show.ng-hide-remove{
    opacity:0;
}
.animate-show.ng-hide-add,
.animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    opacity:1;
}
```